# failed to save images on the server

Tags: php, web

I get this error:

```
Warning: copy(../images/1323841453.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/web07d/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/ControlPanel/upload_image.php on line 78
```

//why it says there is no such file ... but upload_image.php does exist in the directory!?
on the line where this code is:

```
$newname=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/".$image_name;

$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
```

Does it mean they dont have a temporary directory and the directory name where the files are stored is different?!? Where is the directory where the files are saved, and how can I refer to them...['tmp_name'] seems to be the wrong location I think

UPDATE:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/users/web/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/images/1323845800.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/web07d/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/ControlPanel/upload_image.php on line 78

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpjMISTc' to '/home/users/web/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/images/1323845800.jpg' in /hermes/web07d/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/ControlPanel/upload_image.php on line 78

whats causing that error and why?!?

Comment: Just to make sure: Uploaded files only live for the duration of the requests, which uploaded them. Your code is inside a script which handles such a request, right?

Comment: yes.. it is some file that handles the request,, it works on the local host server but not on the site

Answer (score 0):

for uploaded file, use `move_uploaded_file` instead

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having a problem with your destination path.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php66CCpd' to '/images/1323843173.jpg' in /hermes/web07d/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/ControlPanel/upload_image.php on line 78

The path `/hermes/web07d/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/` looks like a root dir for a shared hosting. So you wont have access to `/images`.

What's the desired destination directory and how do you build it (the `$newname` variable)?

Make sure to use absolute paths using either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` for

Comment: I put it in a directory /images/ which is in teh root

Comment: I am going to use this: dirname(__file__)."../images/".$image_name;

Comment: Does the directory `/home/users/web/b1899/moo.koterethayumnet/images/` exist?

Comment: it should be the root of the site.. The code works when I run it in localhost... I used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/".$image_name; so it must exist